# jpa query for arithmetic operation on columns

Tags: jpa

I am somewhat new to jpa. I have created a few simple queries. But now i have a problem with a simple query. I have an entity Payment with 3 columns(Id,Amount1,Amount2). 
Now i want to find all the rows from Payment where Amount1+Amount2 is greater than somevalue.I tried something like:

```
Query query = getEntityManager().createQuery(
  "Select p from Payment p WHERE p.Amount1 + p.Amount2 >' " + someamount +" ' ");
```

But it is not working. I tried using SUM also but that is only one column. 
Can anyone help me with this.
Thanks.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Assuming your entity is properly defined, the following query should work just fine:

```
final BigDecimal threshold = BigDecimal.valueOf(1000);
TypedQuery<Payment> query = getEntityManager().createQuery(
      "SELECT p FROM Payment p WHERE p.Amount1 + p.Amount2> :value",
      Payment.class);
query.setParameter("value", threshold);
List<Payment> results = query.getResultList();
```

Comment: Yes entity is defined properly. because I am able to get values from single column without any problem. The query you have created is same as what i have. Isn't?? But that one is not working. I get error EJB transaction rollout on Select p from Payment p WHERE p.Amount1 + p.Amount2 > 200

Comment: Transaction rollback? Are you doing something else in your method apart from a simple select? Edit your question to include the stack trace and any other JPA operation being done in the same method.

Comment: Oh that was wrong on my part. I was using the results further of the query without checking if its null or not. But still i m not getting any results with the query i posted in first post.

Comment: Are you still using the contacenation method from your original post? Its better to use the parametized version I showed in my answer. Also, whats the result of running the query directly in your SQL tool?

Comment: Thanks for your help and sorry for late reply but i tried a little modification in above query and it worked  getEntityManager().createNativeQuery(      "SELECT * FROM Payment WHERE amount1 + amount2< :value",Payment.class);